# Can't start Android Virtual Device with avdmanager

Tags: android

I have to start AVD without Android studio, using avdmanager.

Preconditions:

- I have installed appium:
  `npm i --location=global appium`
- downloaded `platform-tools`, and added this filter to the path.
- downloaded 'cmdline-tools' folder, and set the ANDROID_HOME, and added this folder\bin to the path.

Now I try to execute the following command:

`avdmanager create avd --name my_avd --package "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"`

As a result, I am stuck for a long time at the point

> Loading local repository...

---

How to start appium test locally without android studio?